# Why can't I install some games/apps to my phone? (samsung galaxy s4)

Tags: applications, google-play-store, system-error, google-apps

I try to download some games, such as crossy roads or, the one i was trying to install in the image, Okay?, and it just says error; couldn't install on USB storage or SD card. But I don't know why, I have loads of room on my phones internal storage and on my SD card. It really annoys me that i cant have the game/app on my phone.[image: Install Error]

Comment: What happens when you sideload an APK? Any error there too or is it only from playstore>

Comment: I can download APK's that's how I get the apps that won't install on my phone, but when I download them it says this file may harm your device but I continue anyway, but the problem with APK's is that there isn't always an APK for the app I want like i cant find an APK for the game I try to install in the photo above - Okay?.